# Javascript regex: How do you get the substring match while using match()

Tags: javascript, regex

From a large minified css file I want to extract the style inside specific media queries. Something like:

```
.some-class{aaa:bbb;ccc:ddd;}@media (min-width: 500px){.some-other-class{aaa:bbb;ccc:ddd;}}.another-class{aaa:bbb;ccc:ddd;}
```

The following regex selects the media queries, with a capturing group for the style inside the media query:

```
regex = new RegExp("@media.\\(min-width:\\d{3,4}px\\){(.+?\\})\\}", "g");
```

The capturing group result is the part I actually want. But when there are more than one hits how do I access multiple capturing group results. When there is only one the result I am after is the second item in the resulting array, when using `str.match(regex);`.

Is the only solution using `regex.exec(str)[1]` in combination with a while loop? Like:

```
while(result != null){
    result = regex.exec(str)[1];
    resultArr.push(result);
}
```

I'd much rather use `match()`...I find that more readable and a more elegant solution, you immediately get an array with you results...although the results I am looking for are only a subset of the results I am getting...

---

I guess I will have to use the last code snippet I gave, `regex.exec(str)`. Ahh well...

Comment: `string.match()` does not keep, discards all the captured values. You have to use `RegExp.exec()`.

Comment: I think you forgot a space or `\s` before `\\d{3,4}`.

Comment: Yes, there must be  a `\s*`, or `\s+`. Sl4rtib4rtf4st, have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/3jp5n54q/ - it is a bit shortened version and uses a regex literal notation.

Comment: [`.match` should give you all of the results you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). The first element in the array will be the whole match and any subsequent results (`result[1] -> result[result.length - 1]`) will be the capturing groups.

Comment: @MikeC: Read on: *If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. **Captured groups are not returned***.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah! I missed the "g" flag. My mistake.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I found that answer but didn't feel this covered my situation as that op wasn't looking for capture groups in multiple hits. But I guess this "If the regular expression includes the g flag, [...]. Captured groups are not returned." gives me my answer, I'll have to use exec(). The string I use in as an example isn't representatieve, the actual string will not have a space at that position.

Comment: The space does not matter, it is covered with `\s*`. The question I linked to contains answers showing how to get all captures "gracefully" (at least with a separate `getMatches` function).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Indeed the second answer would cover this situation. I was mainly wondering if you could do a similar thing with match(), but clearly not as is pointed out in the mdn page for match, which I hadn't read...